# List all group in input?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have list of group and I want to create input and let user choose groups he wants

```
  initialGroups
```

Its ok use for this reason `Bootstrap` `Form.Control`?

```
 <Form.Control
      as="select"
      required
      multiple
      value={initialGroups}
      onChange={onChangeGroups}
      >

      </Form.Control>

 const onChangeGroups = e => {
    const groups = e.target.value.initialGroups;
    setGroups(groups);
  }
```

How to list all groups(name) and let user choose he wants?

Finally I would like to have like this:

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not really understandable. What is initialGroups? When you want to know, if Form.Control is the right component for it, you need to tell us your use case. What do you try to achieve? How is user suppose to decide between elements?

Comment: @IgorGonak I have array of groups (initialGroups). I would like to display all groups in input , and let user  choose groups he wants

Comment: I'm sorry but again it's not sufficient. How does initialGroups look like? Properties?
If you want tto have a list of inputs, that Form.Control is exactly what you are looking for.
What do you mean by "the user should choose groups he wants"? How should the user do it? Does he/she have some kind of radio buttons? selects?

Comment: initialGroups its array(name, and description ) of groups I have . I should be like I added in img @IgorGonak

Comment: look at my answer. is it something you are looking? if yes, please accept so the others can see the solition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple values the user should choose from, you can use Form.Select component. Please look into following sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-cookies-ir1hbx

```
<Form.Select>
    <option hidden>Please choose</option>
    {initialGroups.map((group) => {
      return (
        <option key={group.id} value={group.id}>
          {group.value}
        </option>
      );
    })}
</Form.Select>
```